# n step ahead simulation of SARIMA process using R forecast package

Tags: r, forecasting

I want to simulate an SARIMA process nsteps ahead, with nsim paths. I've already fitted the model, and the 'forecast' package has a 'simulate' function. However as far as I can see whilst it includes an nsim argument it only simulates 1 step ahead? Is this possible with the 'forecast' package?

https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/simulating-from-a-specified-seasonal-arima-model/

What I'm trying to achieve is work out the standard error of the sum of auto-correlated residuals (where the SARIMA model is fitted to the residuals of a model which exhibits auto-correlated residuals). So I want to perform monte-carlo simulation nsteps ahead, sum the values per simulation then work out the standard deviation of the sums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nsim` is the number of observations to simulate ahead. Set it to whatever you like. Here is an example.

```r
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
fit <- auto.arima(USAccDeaths)
autoplot(USAccDeaths, series="Data") +
  autolayer(simulate(fit, nsim=36), series="Simulated")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood the link on the blog. So is there a way to simulate say 1000 paths of 36 points?

Comment: Set up a matrix and write a loop. As done here, for example: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/nnetar-prediction-intervals/

Comment: Ahh right thanks, so each time you call simulate it uses a different random seed I guess?

Comment: Yes, only set the seed once, before simulating anything. Or don't set it at all, in which case it will be essentially randomly chosen.